# How much of an improvement would a 1% weight decrease on an airplane be to the industry?

Tags: airliner, commercial-aviation, airlines, cost, efficiency

Say I thought of a very easy and inexpensive way to reduce the takeoff weight of a commercial airplane (body, fuel and passengers) by 1%. How much would this mean to the industry? Would it make much of a difference, or would the savings be insignificant enough to not really be worth anyone's time?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68430/discussion-on-question-by-theenvironmentalist-how-much-of-an-improvement-would-a).

Answer (score 45):

There is an easy way to get an idea of what magnitude the savings are: The [Breguet equation](http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/Unified_Concepts/Breguet-Range-U2-notes-Fall08(2).pdf) can answer this. You first calculate a [reference aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/how-can-i-calculate-the-fuel-consumption-of-an-airbus-320-200-at-various-loads/8654#8654) and then start all over with one that weighs 1% less. The difference in fuel consumption shows how much fuel is saved per flight.

Our reference design is the A320 which has an L/D of 18 and we let it fly a trip of R = 2,500,000 m. $m_1$ is take-off mass and $m_2$ landing mass. Allow for [3 t of fuel reserves](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3740/what-are-the-icao-fuel-reserve-requirements/3742#3742) and plug that into the Breguet equation, using a fuel burn of $b_f$ = 0.000018 kg/Ns and a speed of Mach 0.78, which equates to $v$ = 262 m/s in 11,000 m altitude:
$$m_1 = m_2 \cdot e^{\frac{R\cdot g\cdot b_f}{v\cdot L/D}}$$
The landing mass $m_2$ is the operational empty mass [OEW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A320_family#Specifications) + 18 t payload + 3 t of fuel reserves = 63.6 t. The take-off mass $m_1$ is 10% higher, so the difference in fuel consumption is 1% of that trip fuel of 6,239 kg or 62 kg. That is not much for a single trip.

But now consider that this one A320 will fly 50,000 trips before it retires. Over its lifetime the 1% in mass reduction will save 3,119 metric tons of fuel. This fills 29.4 [DOT-111 railway tank cars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT-111_tank_car)!

And there are [about 12,000 airliners](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8668/how-many-active-large-commercial-airplanes-are-there) of 150 seats and more and easily twice that number if all regional jets are included, flying [3.8 billion passengers and 53 million tons of freight per year](https://www.icao.int/annual-report-2016/Pages/the-world-of-air-transport-in-2016.aspx) on 35.4 million flights. If we make the heroic assumption that our A320 flight is typical, this translates into global fuel savings of about 2.2 million tons of fuel per year if only 1% of mass could be saved on every airplane.

Another way to approach this is the average fuel efficiency of modern airliners which consume between 3 and 3.5 liters of fuel per 100 passenger kilometers. Using [ICAO's number of 6.6 trillion](https://www.icao.int/sustainability/Pages/FactsFigures.aspx) passenger kilometers in 2015, this would equate to 174 million tons of aviation fuel used per year for revenue passenger transport, assuming a mean density of [kerosene of 0.81 kg/l](https://www.exxonmobil.com/en/aviation/products-and-services/Products/Jet-A-Jet-A-1). The same source gives an average load factor of 80%, so one fifth of seats is empty; the efficiency number above is for a full airplane, however. Therefore, our estimate needs to be increased to 217 million tons.

Saving only 1% of this would reduce fuel consumption by 2.17 million tons per year, which comes pretty close to the first estimate. This is enough to fill more than 41 [Panamax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panamax#Cargo_capacity) oil tankers (the maximum size for the old Panama canal) or 18 [Neopanamax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panamax#Neopanamax) oil tankers.

Or, to look at this from a different angle, with the current [price of kerosene of 1.76 USD per gallon](http://www.iata.org/publications/economics/fuel-monitor/Pages/price-development.aspx), the saved fuel equates to 1.25 billion USD if everyone paid US prices for Jet A-1 fuel. Compared to the average net profit of all airlines per year between 2007 and 2017, [which amounts to 13 billion USD](https://www.statista.com/statistics/232513/net-profit-of-commercial-airlines-worldwide/), this is almost 10% of yearly profits.

Now this doesn’t look so insignificant any more, does it?

Comment: To elaborate on this: 3,119 metric tons of fuel would sell for about 5 million US dollars. So yes, this would be very significant.

Comment: I disagree in the sense that such figures are more misleading. Big numbers blow out our human minds, we can't put them into perspective intuitively. The really important figure is still: **1%**. Whether it's important or significant is another matter, but it's much easier (and more valid!) to grasp it.

Comment: Hm, it actually still doesn't seem like that much to me as a laymen. I feel like airplanes must waste far more fuel than this just due to logistical inefficiencies/preventable delays/etc.

Comment: @Zeus: May I offer a different view? The question is "How much would this mean to the industry", and I offered the perspective for the whole industry. Ask anyone in airline operations how significant 1% fuel savings are and their answer would sound like Koyovis. If **your** mind is blown by big numbers, maybe try to put them into perspective (like I did with the railway car comparison). Or would you prefer an answer along the line of "the numbers are too big to contemplate, so you don't get an honest answer"?

Comment: The complex exponential equation results in "1% reduced mass of aircraft means 1% less fuel used".  Which you can pretty much determine via napkin math.  ;)

Comment: Is 50,000 cycles realistic? That's five and a half cycles per day, seven days a week for 25 years.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I was afraid the number is too low. There are 737s around with more than 70,000 cycles, and the [record holder](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=748823) (Haiwaiian Airlines = very short trips) stands at more than 95,000. The A320 is more recent, but will get there as well.

Comment: @Yakk: Right, and napkin math will give you the absolute amount of fuel as well, doesn't it?

Comment: No, I'm just amused by the fact both answers used a really complex equation to get that 1% reduction number.  Note that http://www.indexmundi.com/energy/?product=jet-fuel says 5 million barrels/day of all jet fuel consumption.  1% of that is then 50 thousand/day, times 365 is 18 million barrels. At 42 galleons per barrel, and your 1.76$/galleon, that gives us 1.33 billion USD.  However, this was consumption for all uses; some subset of that is used by commercial airlines.  Still, this second derviation validates yours!

Comment: @PeterKämpf I think that the last full paragraph of your answer, where you compare cost of the fuel to yearly profits, is really the most meaningful assessment of how much it matters to the industry, and you might consider focusing more on that than on how many tankers and so on. Those absolute numbers/sizes are interesting, and yeah, they're really big, but everything about the whole industry is really big, so they don't give as strong a sense of how much it matters to the industry.

Comment: @Jefromi: It is the last paragraph because I added it last. I first had to research the numbers, while the Breguet equation was copied from an earlier answer ;-)

Comment: @Yakk: Look at it this way: Both answers use a proven equation to conclude that 1% of weight savings really amounts to 1% of fuel saved. Might be trivial, but that's how engineers think.

Comment: @PeterKämpf Right, I'm not surprised it ended up there, but my suggestion was to edit, to try to end up with fewer people thinking what Zeus mentioned.

Comment: Is the tanker capacity off? ... tankers are in the 100,000 ton range, so I'd believe 41 Panamax tankers rather than 4,100 ... were you carrying the full fuel requirements rather than just the 1% saving?

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Thank you for spotting this. Embarrassingly, I took the full fuel consumption instead of the 1% for the tanker comparison. Corrected.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding in a link to the Neopanamax, since I believe this is what the reference to "17" in the penultimate paragraph meant in comparison to the "41" that proceeded it.

Answer (score 23):

One % of takeoff weight is *huge*. On a B747 with MTOW of 300 tons, that is a weight saving of 3,000 kg, weight that needs not be lugged around for the couple of decades that the aircraft will be flying.

At the aircraft factory where I used to work, there were Idea Boxes everywhere where one could deposit suggestions for weight savings, every kg saved adds to improvement of fuel economy. How much depends on range and a whole lot of other factors, and can be quantified for specific aircraft.

1%. *Yuuge*.

If we make an estimate for a B747-400 flying maximum range of 12,700 km according to slide 7/14 out of [this presentation](https://www.slideserve.com/rhona/intro-to-aerodynamics-learning-objectives).

[image]

MTOW is given as 400,000 kg, fuel weight as 175,000 kg, this makes $W_{final}$ = MTOW - $W_{fuel}$ = 225,000 kg. With 1% saving, MTOW is reduced to 396,000 kg. Range stays the same if $\frac{W_{init}}{W_{final}}$ stays the same. So the new $W_{final}$ becomes:

$$ W_{final} = \frac{396,000}{400,000}\cdot 225,000 = 222,750 kg$$

$W_{final}$ is again MTOW - $W_{fuel}$ =>

$$W_{fuel} = MTOW - W_{final} = 396,000 - 222,750 = 173,250 kg$$

Final fuel saving is 175,000 - 173,250 = **1,750 kg**

For one long distance, maximum range flight, a reduction of 1% in TO weight saves 1,750 kg of fuel. Every percent of weight savings equates to a percent of fuel saved. Every trip, for 2 - 3 decades.

Comment: MTOW of 300 tons?  Try 438 tons.

Comment: There you go, even Yuger.

Comment: Hm, from what I read, taxiing burns 1.5 tons of fuel per 10 mins... whereas this supposedly seems to translate into a 62 kg fuel consumption (from the above answer)? So like, equivalent to ~30 seconds of taxiing? Yet I don't get the impression airlines really care enough to try to minimize the number of seconds to such a granularity. Am I correct, wrong, or missing something?

Comment: You take savings from any source you can. Taxiing is necessary anyway, regardless of the MTOW savings. Would you not want to save 62 kg of fuel every trip for 20 years, because you need to spend fuel taxiing?

Comment: 1,750kg is just 1% of the original fuel weight of 175,000kg. But that assumes the weight is being shaved off of every part of the airplane proportionally, rather than being reduced in one area (i.e. structure) while leaving other areas (i.e. passenger weight) the same.

Comment: Again, reasonably complex mathematics that generates the conclusion "reduce aircraft mass by 1% and save 1% fuel".  Which is the kind of conclusion you'd be surprised if it *wasn't* true.

Comment: @Yakk I don't think I'd upvote a question which made the assumption that it was true without justifying it.  So many things [don't scale the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law) in science, and planes are quite complicated balanced pieces of machinery. I think it's very important to demonstrate a justification for assuming they do.

Comment: @CortAmmon 100% agreed with you there. Anybody can state anything, and they do. What justifies the statement though? How can we know that fuel quantity used scales linearly with weight, and not for instance quadratically like it does with airspeed?

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist Reduce the payload by 1% and you also save 1% fuel consumption. That is why there are payload-range diagrams.