# What is the specific consumption of an A320 at Mach 0.78 and 11,000 metre altitude?

Tags: airbus-a320, fuel-consumption

I am currently doing a dissertation on an electric drive system on planes and I need help. I can't find the specific fuel burn rate for an Airbus A320; if anyone could help it would be great. Also a link or solution to calculating specific fuel consumption and known fuel burn would be much appreciated. It is so I could calculate the fuel used from added weight in the Breguet equation, but there is no average fuel consumption for the formula in kg/Ns.

Comment: Take a look at these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_economy_in_aircraft

Comment: [This answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/45439/how-much-of-an-improvement-would-a-1-weight-decrease-on-an-airplane-be-to-the-i/45443#45443) by Peter Kämpf is using the Breguet equation for exactly what you are looking for. I think you can use the parameters from there.

Comment: Yeah thanks I seen that question hence why I used these parameters but what I really wanted to know is where 0.000018 kg/Ns came from. Couldn't find it anywhere and for my dissertation something like that would either need to be calculated or reference and obviously cant reference an answer to a question. Not a reliable source.

Comment: The $0.000018 \frac{kg}{Ns}$ is the [Thrust-specific fuel consumption](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust-specific_fuel_consumption). Mind the units, $\frac{kg}{Ns}$ vs. $\frac{g}{kNs}$ in the [wiki table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust-specific_fuel_consumption#Typical_values_of_SFC_for_thrust_engines). $0.000018 \frac{kg}{Ns} = 18 \frac{g}{kNs}$. And, by the way, Peter Kämpf ***is*** a reliable source ;-)

Comment: You may add into the question description your calculation leading to the figure you put in the comments so that answers can focus on what you haven't already figured out by yourself.

Comment: @Bianfable: Actually, [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/how-can-i-calculate-the-fuel-consumption-of-an-airbus-320-200-at-various-loads/8654?r=SearchResults&s=1|76.5010#8654) is even more to the point.

Comment: Thank You guys much appreciated :) Wish me luck in my dissertation and I'm not allowed to reference wiki or any forum. Thanks again :)